# Is there a way to run an express App in Electron?

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I am new to Electron and I have an Express App running on Localhost. Is there a way to have the same app run in Electron?

Comment: There is a way. Electron is Node+Chromium. Do you have specific problems with doing that?

Comment: Yes, how can I render files that are in the express app? I have an express app generated using express generator and my biggest issue is to have the routes i have in the app rendered

Comment: The same way you do in Node. You will serve them from `localhost` server and consume in Electron renderer process with HTTP requests. I consider this less efficient but more universal way to exchange data between main and renderer processes.

Comment: @estus Can you please add or reference a sample?

Comment: @fedeteka I have no specific example at hand. Search for 'electron express'. E.g. https://gist.github.com/maximilian-lindsey/a446a7ee87838a62099d/

Comment: @estus Thanks for the link!

Comment: You can answer you tried